# PreparedStatement ResultSet - Column contains selected column name as String instead of actual values of selected column

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement, resultset

Using a PreparedStatement in Java I have run into a weird situation that I couldn't resolve via SO or searching the web.

```
preStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT ?, Date FROM " + paramTable + " WHERE [...]");
preStatement.setString(1, paramColumn);
ResultSet rs = preStatement.executeQuery();
preStatement.close();
```

The problem here is that the column `paramColumn` that is selected from the `paramTable` table only contains `float`-Type values in the Database, however when I execute the PreparedStatement the first column comes back with database type `nvarchar`.

For example if I `SELECT MyValue, Date FROM ValueTable`
the `ResultSet` would look like

```
________________________
| MyValue | Date       |
| MyValue | 2014-09-09 |
| MyValue | 2014-09-10 |
....
```

while it should look like

```
________________________
| MyValue | Date       |
| 26,567  | 2014-09-09 |
| 28,623  | 2014-09-10 |
....
```

When I execute that SQL Statement in the Management Console I get the correct values no problem but in Java the column always contains the column name as a `String`.

Comment: You can not use a  placeholder as column name

Comment: I don't think you can use a `PreparedStatement` like that. `preStatement.setString(1, paramColumn);` sets a string literal, not a column name.

Comment: Indeed, concatenation worked as suggested by @sidgate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate the column name in the query string

```
preStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT "+paramColumn+", Date FROM " + paramTable + " WHERE [...]");
```